# Multi Series 2d column chart from MySQL in FusionCharts

Tags: php, mysql, charts, fusioncharts

I'm trying to create a 2D chart with MySQL data that would show two data ranges. For previous and current results. I have to use two queries

1. `"SELECT name, points FROM results GROUP BY name";`
2. `"SELECT name, pointsold FROM results GROUP BY name";`

How to combine this in code?

```
<?php

        // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
        $strQuery = "SELECT name, points FROM results GROUP BY name";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result) {
            // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
            $arrData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "Rozkład punktacji",
              "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
              "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
              "borderAlpha"=> "20",
              "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
              "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
              "plotBorderAlpha"=> "0",
              "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
              "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
              "showValues" => "1",
              "divlineColor" => "#999999",
              "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
              "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
            )
            );

            $arrData["data"] = array();

    // Push the data into the array
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["nazwa"],
                "value" => $row["punkty"]
                )
            );
            }

            /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

            $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

    /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

            $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-2", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

            // Render the chart
            $columnChart->render();

            // Close the database connection
            $dbhandle->close();
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data from your SQL query in `$result` variable, and then create empty arrays according to FusionCharts format for multi-series charts and then push values in them.

You can [check this example for the same](https://github.com/sikrigagan/FusionCharts-Samples/tree/master/PHP/Multi-Series-DB-MySQL).